# KendoUI Grid Enum row filtering fails

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am one day old into Kendo, so I believe, I'm missing the obvious.

The grid seems to get stuck when tried to filter with Enum values set. [Test Link](http://dojo.telerik.com/aQikI/5)

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { 
     field: "category", 
     values: [{text: "Beverages", value: 1 }, {text: "Food", value: 2 }],
     filterable: { mode: "row", cell: { showOperators: false, operator: "eq" } }
    }
  ],
  dataSource: [{ category: 1 }, { category: 2 } ],
  filterable: {mode: "row"}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

worked it out finally, missing type was all it seems needed. [Demo Link](http://dojo.telerik.com/aQikI/8)

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { 
     field: "category", type: "number", 
     values: [{text: "Beverages", value: 1 }, {text: "Food", value: 2 }],
     filterable: { mode: "row", cell: { showOperators: false, operator: "eq" } }
    }
  ],
  dataSource: [{ category: 1 }, { category: 2 } ],
  filterable: {mode: "row"}
});
</script>
```